# Linked List Delete Function Modification Issues in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I am studying for a test and I am having trouble debugging my linked list practice exam questions. I am having issues with the different modification to the delete functions he wants us to do. Specifically, my deleteEven is an endless look and my deleteNthNode does not work as it is supposed to. Because I am struggling with these two I'm not even sure where to start with deleting every other element in the list. I'd appreciate the help as I want to completely understand this topic before I move to stacks and queues! :)

Below is my code:

```
    /*
Q1: 
Try implementing the functions shown in class on your own: 
    check:  node creation 
    check:  insertion at the end of a linked list,
    check:  insertion at the head of a linked list, 
    check:  a list printing function.
Q2: 
    check: Write a recursive printList() function.
Q3:
    check: Write a recursive tailInsert() function.
Q4:
    check: Write a function that inserts nodes at the beginning of the linked list.
Q5:
    check: Write a recursive function that prints a linked list in reverse order. 
           The function signature is: void printReverse(node *head);
Q6:
    check: Write an iterative destroyList() function that frees all the nodes in a linked list.
Q7:
    check: Now implement destroyList() recursively.
Q8:
    - Write a function that deletes the nth element from a linked list. 
      If the linked list doesn't even have n nodes, don't delete any of them. 
      The function signature is: node *deleteNth(node *head, int n). 
     - Try implementing the function iteratively and recursively. 
     - (In terms of how to interpret n, you can start counting your nodes from zero or one; your choice.)
Q9:
    - Write a function that deletes every other element in a linked list. 
    - (Try writing it both ways: one where it starts deleting at the head of the list, 
    - and one where it starts deleting at the element just after the head of the list.)
    - Can you write this both iteratively and recursively?
Q10:
    - Write a function that deletes all even integers from a linked list.
Q11:
    - Write a function that takes a sorted linked list and an element to be inserted into that linked list,
      and inserts the element in sorted order. 
      The function signature is: node *insertSorted(node *head, int n);
Q12:
    - One of the problems with the first insertNode() function from today is that it 
      requires us to call it using head = insertNode(head, i). 
      That's a bit dangerous, because we could forget the "head =" part very easily. 
      Re-write the function so that it takes a pointer to head, 
      thereby allowing it to directly modify the contents of head without any need for a return value. 
      The function signature is: void insertNode(node **head, int data). 
      The function will be called using insertNode(&head, i).
*/

//come back to
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Basic linked list node struct; contains 'data' and 'next' pointer.
// What happens if we type "node *next" instead of "struct node *next"?
typedef struct node
{
    // data field
    int data;

    // the next node in the list
    struct node *next;
} node;

// Allocate a new node. Initialize its fields. Return the pointer.
// We call this from our insertion functions.
node *createNode(int data)
{
    node *ptr = NULL;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("space could not be allocated\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

// Insert into the end of the linked list. Return the head of the linked list.
// (What is the order (Big-Oh) of this function?)

/*
node *insertNode(node *head, int data)
{    
    node *temp;
    if (head == NULL)
        return createNode(data);

    for(temp = head; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        ;
    temp->next = createNode(data);

    return head;
}
*/

node *insertNodeFront(node *head, int data)
{
    node *temp;
    if(head == NULL)
        return createNode(data);

    temp = createNode(data);
    temp->next = head;

    return temp;
}   

// Simple function to print the contents of a linked list.
void printList(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty List\n");
        return;
    }

    for(; head != NULL; head = head->next)
        printf("%d ", head->data);

    printf("\n");
}

void printListRecursiveHelper(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    printf("%d%c", head->data, (head->next == NULL) ? '\n' : ' ');
    printListRecursiveHelper(head->next);
}

void printListRecursive(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("empty list\n");
        return;
    }
    printListRecursiveHelper(head);
}
// Q3: - Write a recursive tailInsert() function.

node *tailInsert(node *head, int data)
{
    if(head->next == NULL)
    {
        node *temp;
        temp = createNode(data);
        temp->next = NULL;
        head->next = temp;
        return temp;
    }
    return tailInsert(head->next, data);
}   
//Q5: Write a recursive function that prints a linked list in reverse order. 
void printReverse(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    printReverse(head->next);

    printf("%d ", head->data);
}

// Q6: - Write an iterative destroyList() function that frees all the nodes in a linked list.
// Got code from internet, memorize it
/* Function to delete the entire linked list */
void destroyList (struct node** head)
{
   struct node* current = *head;
   struct node* next;

   while (current != NULL) 
   {
       next = current->next;
       free(current);
       current = next;
   }


   *head = NULL;
}

// Q7:  - Now implement destroyList() recursively.
// Look up online, need to examine why it deson't work
node *destroyListRecursive(node * head)
{
    if (head != NULL) 
    {
        destroyListRecursive(head->next);
        free(head);
    }

    return NULL;
}

/* Q8:
    - Write a function that deletes the nth element from a linked list. 
    - If the linked list doesn't even have n nodes, don't delete any of them. 
    - Try implementing the function iteratively and recursively. 
    - (In terms of how to interpret n, you can start counting your nodes from zero or one; your choice.)
*/

node *deleteNth(node *head, int n)
{
    /*
    int i;
    node*current;
    node *prev;

    current = head;

    while(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        current = current->next;   
    }

    prev = current;
    current = head->next->next;
    */
    return head;
}

/*
Q9:
    - Write a function that deletes every other element in a linked list. 
    - (Try writing it both ways: one where it starts deleting at the head of the list, 
    - and one where it starts deleting at the element just after the head of the list.)
    - Can you write this both iteratively and recursively?
*/

/* deletes alternate nodes of a list starting with head */
//got code from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-alternate-nodes-of-a-linked-list/
void deleteAltHead(struct node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    struct node *node = head->next;

    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    /* Change the next link of head */
    head->next = node->next;

    /* free memory allocated for node */
    free(node);

    /* Recursively call for the new next of head */
    deleteAltHead(head->next);
}

void deleteOtherTail()
{

}

//Q10:  - Write a function that deletes all even integers from a linked list.
void deleteEvenInts(node **head)
{

}

// Q11: - Write a function that takes a sorted linked list and an element to be inserted into that linked list,
//        and inserts the element in sorted order. 
node *insertSorted(node *head, int n)
{    
    struct node *current;
    struct node *newNode = createNode(n);

    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (head == NULL || head->data >= newNode->data)
    {
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL &&
               current->next->data < newNode->data)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        newNode->next = current->next;
        current->next = newNode;
    }

    return current;
    //or should it return head?
}



// Q12:  Re-write the insertNode() function so that it takes a pointer to head
void insertNode(node **head, int data)
{
    node *newNode = createNode(data);

    while (*head != NULL)
    {
        head = &(*head)->next;
    }

    newNode->next = *head;
    *head = newNode;
}

// Q10: Write a function that deletes all even integers from a linked list.
void deleteEven(node **head)
{
    node *current = *head;
    node *next = current;
    node *prev = NULL;

    for ( ; current != NULL; )
    {
        next = current->next;

        if( current->data %2)
        {
            if(prev != NULL)
            {
                prev->next = next;
                free(current);
                current = next;
            }
            else
            {
                free(current);
                current = next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            prev = current;
            current = next;
        }
    }
}

//Q8: Write a function that deletes the nth element from a linked list. If the linked list doesn't even have n nodes, don't delete any of them. 
node *deleteNthNode(node *head, int n)
{
    int i = 0; 
    int nBigger = 0;
    node *current = head;
    node *prev = current;
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
        if (current == NULL)
        {
            nBigger = 1;
        }
    }

    if(nBigger == 1)
    {
        return head;
    }

    prev = current->next;
    free(current);

    return head;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, r;

    // The head of our linked list. If we don't initialize it to NULL, our
    // insertNode() function might segfault.
    node *head = NULL;

    srand(time(NULL));

    // Populate the linked list with random integers. We are inserting into the
    // head of the list each time.
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Inserting %d...\n", r = rand() % 20 + 1);
        insertNode(&head, r);
    }

    head = insertNodeFront(head, 1);

    tailInsert(head, 5);

    // Print the linked list.
    printList(head);
    printf("\n");
    printReverse(head);
    printf("\n\n");

    // Print the linked list using our recursive function.
    printListRecursive(head);

    //destroyList(&head);
    deleteAltHead(head);
    printf("\n");
    printList(head);
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    struct node *node = head->next;

    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    /* Change the next link of head */
    head->next = node->next;

    /* free memory allocated for node */
    free(node);

    /* Recursively call for the new next of head */
}
     deleteEven(&head);

  //  head = destroyListRecursive(head);
    printf("\n");
    printList(head);

    node *head2 = NULL;
    insertNode(&head2, 1);
    insertNode(&head2, 2);
    insertNode(&head2, 4);

    printf("\n");
    printList(head2);

    insertSorted(head2, 3);
    printf("\n");
    deleteNthNode(head, 1);
    printList(head2);


    //destroyListRecursive(head2);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a relevant read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks, taking a look at it now.